# How to fix not enough space when trying to convert to GPT from MBR without losing data?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I have a nearly 1TB Ext. Hard Drive which has 2 partitions: One which is about 350GB with 250GB already taken up (FAT32), and another which is roughly 580GB with no space taken up (NTFS). I need to at least convert the NTFS partition from MBR to GPT, but no matter what software I use, I get the same error; there not enough pace before the first partition. I have nowhere to back up the 250GB of data already stored on the disk, but can't lose any of the data either.

How do I fix this and keep all existing data on the drive?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have 580GB of space for backing up the data, though?

Comment: If that data is of any importance, you should have a valid backup strategy. Hardware fails sometimes. Malware attacks happen. Humans make mistakes. Consider dealing with this before converting to GPT, there are no real benefits if the drive is less than 3 TB big and not bootable.

Comment: Why do you think you need GPT though?

Comment: You might add the layout of your partitions to your question. Which one comes first?

Answer (score 0):

Copy all your files from the first partition to second, just in case.

Use GParted to shrink/move the first partition towards the 'right' so that it has at least 1 MB or 2 MB in "Free space preceding". It will take a few hours to move the entire thing.

*(Or, because you already made a copy of all files in step 1, you can destroy the partition and create a new one at the new location, then copy files back...)*

---

MBR and GPT are not partition formats – they are *partition table* formats. So you always convert the whole disk between the two; it does not make sense to convert a single partition.

If your disk is well under 2TiB and only has 2 partitions, then switching from MBR to GPT won't actually give you much as you're not reaching any MBR-specific limits anyway. The partition table type won't affect performance either.